# Not able to Insert Data with Foreign Keys struts2

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

I have 3 entities (`Medecin` , `Patient` , `Rendezvous`)

Medecin with `Idmed` , Patient with `Idpat` are foreign key with `ManyToOne` relationship in Rendezvous.

When I add a `Medecin` or a `Patient` via a form , the Data is perfectly stored .

But when I try to add a `Rendezvous` , using a Form with two ,  struts2 select tag , `<:select../>` who are populated with the list of Id of Patient and Medecin .

Nothing happen.

I have a return success , but the Data is not stored .

How to fix that ?

My form, Rendezvous.jsp

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form_main">
            <h4 class="heading"><strong>Planifier un </strong> Rendezvous <span></span></h4>
            <div class="form">
            <s:form action="Ajoutrdv" id="Ajoutrdv" namepace="/pages" theme="bootstrap" cssClass="bs-example form-horizontal">
                <s:textfield label="Id du Rendezvous" type="Number" min="1" required="" placeholder="Entrer l'ID du RDV"  name="idrdv"/>
                <s:select label="Id du Patient" headerKey="-1" headerValue="" list="%{Patient}" listKey="idpat" name="idpat"  required="" onchange="getData(this.value)"/>
                <s:select label="Id du Medecin" headerKey="-1" headerValue="" list="%{Medecin}" listKey="idmed" name="idmed"  required="" onchange="getData(this.value)"/>
                <s:textfield type="Date" required="" name="date"></s:textfield>
                <s:textfield type="Time" required="" name="heure"></s:textfield>
                <s:textarea label="Motif" required="" name="motif"></s:textarea>


                <caption><s:submit cssClass="btn btn-primary" value="Enregistrer"/></caption>
            </s:form>
        </div>
```

My action in struts2.xml

```
<package name="Ajoutrdv" namespace="/pages" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="Ajoutrdv" class="controller.FormRDVAction" method="Ajoutrdv">
        <result name="success">/pages/accueil.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/pages/Rendezvous.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

FormRDVAction

```
public class FormRDVAction extends ActionSupport {
private Integer idrdv;
private Medecin idmed;
private Patient idpat;
private String date;
private String heure;
private String motif;
private List<Rendezvous> Rendezvous;
// getters setters

// Add action
public String Ajoutrdv() {


     RendezvousDAO rdvDAO= RendezvousDAO.getInstance();

     Rendezvous R = new Rendezvous();
     R.setIdmed(idmed);
     R.setIdpat(idpat);
     R.setIdrdv(idrdv);
     R.setDate(date);
     R.setHeure(heure);
     R.setMotif(motif);
     rdvDAO.saveRendezvous(R);
    return SUCCESS;

}
}
```

RendezvousDAO

```
public void saveRendezvous(Rendezvous Rendezvous) {
    log.info("********** Debut saveRendezvous RendezvousDAO **********");
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().openSession();
    Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
    try {

        session.save(Rendezvous);
          if (!trans.wasCommitted()) {
        trans.commit();
          }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.fatal(e.getMessage());
        trans.rollback();

    } finally {
        session.close();

}      
}
```

Finally , mapping class Rendezvous.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rendezvous")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Rendezvous.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Rendezvous r"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Rendezvous.findByIdrdv", query = "SELECT r FROM Rendezvous r WHERE r.idrdv = :idrdv"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Rendezvous.findByDate", query = "SELECT r FROM Rendezvous r WHERE r.date = :date"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Rendezvous.findByHeure", query = "SELECT r FROM Rendezvous r WHERE r.heure = :heure"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Rendezvous.findByMotif", query = "SELECT r FROM Rendezvous r WHERE r.motif = :motif")})
public class Rendezvous implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idrdv")
private Integer idrdv;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "date")
private String date;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "heure")
private String heure;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "motif")
private String motif;
@JoinColumn(name = "idpat", referencedColumnName = "idpat")
@ManyToOne(optional = false , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Patient idpat;
@JoinColumn(name = "idmed", referencedColumnName = "idmed")
@ManyToOne(optional = false , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Medecin idmed;

public Rendezvous() {
}

public Rendezvous(Integer idrdv) {
    this.idrdv = idrdv;
}

public Rendezvous(Integer idrdv, String date, String heure, String motif) {
    this.idrdv = idrdv;
    this.date = date;
    this.heure = heure;
    this.motif = motif;
}

public Integer getIdrdv() {
    return idrdv;
}

public void setIdrdv(Integer idrdv) {
    this.idrdv = idrdv;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getHeure() {
    return heure;
}

public void setHeure(String heure) {
    this.heure = heure;
}

public String getMotif() {
    return motif;
}

public void setMotif(String motif) {
    this.motif = motif;
}

public Patient getIdpat() {
    return idpat;
}

public void setIdpat(Patient idpat) {
    this.idpat = idpat;
}

public Medecin getIdmed() {
    return idmed;
}

public void setIdmed(Medecin idmed) {
    this.idmed = idmed;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (idrdv != null ? idrdv.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Rendezvous)) {
        return false;
    }
    Rendezvous other = (Rendezvous) object;
    if ((this.idrdv == null && other.idrdv != null) || (this.idrdv != null && !this.idrdv.equals(other.idrdv))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "mapping.Rendezvous[ idrdv=" + idrdv + " ]";
}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have data in the service and you use right method to save it?

Comment: Well im able to save data , via the save method in DAO class (savePatient in PatientDAO , saveMedecin in MedecinDAO) works great and are similar to saveRendezVous method in RendezVousDAO . The table exist in mysql and when i insert data via mysql , it works , but via struts2 form , nothing happen so i still dont know what happen

Comment: You didn't submit the form, so the data is not transferred through http and struts2 is not able to handle data.

Comment: ok could you tell me where's exactly my error in my code ? that may be the problem. When i click in the submit button , i can access the action and it return me a success page , but nothing saved

Comment: can you show me the data that is not saved?

Comment: ok ill edit my post in 5 min and show you pic of the data

Comment: I don't need the pic of the data, i need the code where the data lost.

Comment: If you are talking about the code to save Data , its in `FormRDVAction` , method `Ajoutrdv` , you can see it in my main post . The user put the Data via the form web page and click submit , then normally the `Ajoutrdv`  action method , should save the Data and return a success . there no code for Lost data

Comment: So where you see the data lost, in the database?

Comment: The lost data is not seen in mysql . It just empty . The Data is not stored when i submit it via struts2 , and it only happen with this class , the other classes works great .When i insert data directly via mysql in `Rendezvous` , it's stored . I dont know if there are some restrict constraint on Insert . Lol Thanks for your help anyway . if i cannot find solution for that i well let it , and continue with symfony framework ^^

Comment: How it is related to S2? If you're submitting id-s then fetch entity be id and use it.